# Having trouble POSTing to Play framework in scala

Tags: scala, rest, playframework

Hello I am new to Play and even Scala and I can't seem to post Json properly to the server.

I am trying to implement a basic REST API. I have the gets working but I can't seem to Post data and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong

Here is my controller class

```
  class Items extends Controller {

  implicit val itemReads = Json.reads[Item]
  implicit val itemWrites = Json.writes[Item]


  // GET: /api/items
  def index = Action {
    println("Items Index")
    val items = Json.arr(Item.getItems)
    Ok(items)
  }

  // POST: /api/items
  def create = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) {
    request => val item = request.body.validate[Item]
      item.fold(errors => {BadRequest(Json.obj("error" -> JsError.toJson(errors)))}, result => {Created})
  }

  // GET: /api/items/:id
  def get(id: Int) = Action {
    println("Here is item " + id)
    val item = Item.findById(id)
    if (item != null) {
      Ok(Json.toJson(item))
    } else {
      NotFound(Json.obj("error" -> 404, "message" -> "Item Not Found"))
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my javascript function for posting the data:

```
function testCreateAnItem() {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:9000/api/items",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {id:7, name:"NewGnome"},
    success: function(data) {console.log("Success: Created " + data.name)},
    error: function() {console.log("Error: Couldn't create new item")}
})
}
```

The error I get is this:

For request 'POST /api/items' [Invalid Json: Unrecognized token 'id': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@4fa5f73d; line: 1, column: 4]]

I'm sure I'm making a dumb error but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time

UPDATE:

This is my item class

```
case class Item(id: Int, name: String)
```

Comment: what is Item, can you add code for Item class/model

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify()` around your JSON object: data: `JSON.stringify({id:7, name:"NewGnome"})`.

Comment: @Adi I've added the item class

Comment: @Kris stringily worked, cheers dude